# When do I have to declare session_start();?

Tags: php, session, authentication

So Im a beginner when it comes to PHP so I need a little help. I am trying to figure out when to start the session. Should I do it when the user first registers or what about when they log in?

Also, are sessions 'universal' meaning when I check a session will it work or do I have to include a file to all pages that check if someone has a session?

Answer (score 19):

*"Should I do it when the user first registers or what about when they log in?"*

You should do it **every time** you want to get or set any session information. Data stored in the `$_SESSION` array will only be available after the session is started.

*"Also, are sessions 'universal' meaning when I check a session will it work or do I have to include a file to all pages that check if someone has a session?"*

Calling `session_start()` is all you need to create a session. If a session was already created, that session will be used.

Comment: Showing the code that checks if a session was started, and only start if it wasn't already started would be good practice.  `if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start;}`

Comment: `session_start()` also needs to be before any HTML output

Answer (score 5):

just to session_start() once in every file you access the $_SESSION variable. best would be to do it in a central spot. for example a file which is included in every of your applications files.