# Do I need to add session_start() in include pages if I have it on the parent file?

Tags: php-5.3, php

I have this code below as as an example .. should I use session_start() again in all the included scripts if I already have it on top in the parent file ..

here's parent.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'child1.php';
include 'child2.php';

//
?>
```

do child1.php and child2.php need session_start() as well in order to use session variables in them or is the first session_start of the parent.php file enough for the include files to use session variables?

Comment: Read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158139/when-do-i-have-to-declare-session-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you only want `session_start()` called once.

> Calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you .. I thought I may need to include them in the included files too.. thanks for the clarification