# PHP : session variable having an undefined offset error

Tags: php, session

I am a newbie in PHP programming. I am creating a simple login form with sessions. I am passing two session variables : **`$_SESSION['username']`** and **`$_SESSION['logon']`**. Here is my code:

```
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rowcount == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logon'] == "online";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:../index.php?username=$_SESSION[username]");

    }
```

The problem is that when I try to access the `$_SESSION['username']`variable,  it gives me the appropriate value stored in it, but when I try to access the `$_SESSION['logon']` variable, it gives me an undefined offset error.

Comment: '== ' this is comparision , you should assign '=' and the other thing `session_start(); `should be first line

Comment: session_start(); at the top of the page only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:-

1.`session_start();` need to be top on the each page(best to add in separate file and then include that file to every other file)

2.

```
$_SESSION['logon'] == "online"; //it's comparison not assignment
```

need to be:-

```
$_SESSION['logon'] = "online"; // now it's an assignment
```

Note:- you can get `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers ...` multiple times, when you use `session_start()` in middle of the page.

Reference:-

1.[Why setcookie( ) and session_start( ) Want to Be at the Top of the Page](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-php-5/0596005601/ch08s06.html)

2.[Where exactly do I put a SESSION_START?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start)

3.[When do I have to declare session_start();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158139/when-do-i-have-to-declare-session-start)

Comment: but shouldn't I start the session after I have verifed he is a user in my database?

Comment: @IrfanSindhi  starting session in middle of the page cause issues,Later you will get that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how? Im kind of confused.

Comment: @IrfanSindhi  check the reference link in my answer

Comment: Thank you for the extra answer. It was really helpful.

Comment: @IrfanSindhi  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SESSION['logon'] == "online";
```

is not the same as

```
$_SESSION['logon'] = "online";
```

The first is a comparision.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My code works works now. Thank you.